# Objective C - Asking to save before you quit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an Objective-C/Cocoa text-editor I'm working on(It's a mac app, not iOS).

The current challenge I'm facing is having a dialog when someone try to quit without saving.

I already have a shared bool called `issavedsomewhere` to tell if the user has saved or not. I even have the textview data available as a shared variable, so I can access it from any class.

I'm thinking that I'd put the save dialog in the `(void)applicationWillTerminate` method.

**My current saving code is simple:**

```
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    // NSInteger result;

    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"txt"]];
    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){

        //OK button pushed
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            // Close panel before handling errors
            [panel orderOut:self];
            // Do what you need to do with the selected path

            NSString *selpath = [[panel URL] path];

            NSError *error;

            BOOL didOK = [[theDATA.textvieww string]writeToFile:selpath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

            if(!didOK){
                //error while saving
                NSLog(@"Couldn't Save!!! -> %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);

            }else{
                //success!
                theDATA.issavedsomewhere=YES;
                theDATA.filepath=selpath;
                theDATA.filename=[[[panel URL] path] lastPathComponent];
            }

        }/*Button other than the OK button was pushed*/
        else{


        }
    }];
```

All it is, is an `NSSavePanel` that pops up and asks where you want to save.

The problem is that when I add it to `(void)applicationWillTerminate`, it doesn't wait for the user to answer.

Your help and ideas are appreciated:)

Comment: Isn't that all covered by `NSDocument`?

Comment: @trojanfoe to be honest I never heard of NSDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this within the Cocoa framework, such as by using `NSDocument` and its ilk. However, it is possible to do what you want to do.

You first want to return `NSTerminateLater` in `applicationShouldTerminate:`:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    if (theDATA.issavedsomewhere) {
       return NSTerminateLater;
    }
    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

Then, you handler should ultimately call `[NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES]` when it is done:

```
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    // NSInteger result;

    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"txt"]];
    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){

        //OK button pushed
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            // Close panel before handling errors
            [panel orderOut:self];
            // Do what you need to do with the selected path

            NSString *selpath = [[panel URL] path];

            NSError *error;

            BOOL didOK = [[theDATA.textvieww string]writeToFile:selpath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

            if(!didOK){
                //error while saving
                NSLog(@"Couldn't Save!!! -> %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);

            }else{
                //success!
                theDATA.issavedsomewhere=YES;
                theDATA.filepath=selpath;
                theDATA.filename=[[[panel URL] path] lastPathComponent];
            }

        }/*Button other than the OK button was pushed*/
        else{


        }
        [NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];
    }];
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I'll definitely look into NSDocument. I'm not too sure what it is.

Comment: How / where does the code containing the `NSSavePanel` get called? Does the `applicationShouldTerminate:` method need to trigger this code?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to just save in a temp file and on launch check to see if the tempfile exists and perhaps ask the user if he want to use it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since changes to my data can happen in multiple places I simply post a "data modified" notification whenever this happens:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:@"DataModifiedNotification"
                      object:self];
```

My app delegate has a `dataSaved` property and adds itself as an observer of this notification and sets its value to `NO` whenever the data is mutated:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {    
    self.dataSaved = YES; // set to NO when data mutated
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
       addObserver:self
          selector:@selector(receiveDataModifiedNotification:)                                                     
              name:@"DataModifiedNotification"
             object:nil];
}

-(void)receiveDataModifiedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
     self.dataSaved = NO;
}
```

The the app delegate asks the user if they really want to quit to give
them the opportunity to save the data (done elsewhere):

```
 -(NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
     if (!self.dataSaved) {
          NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
          alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyleWarning;
          alert.messageText = @"Data unsaved!";
          alert.informativeText = @"Do you really want to Quit the application?";
          [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Quit"];
          [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
          [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window 
                       completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
             const BOOL shouldQuit = returnCode == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn;
             [NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate: shouldQuit];
           }];
           return NSTerminateLater;
     }
    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

*Note:* Set app property `NSSupportsSuddenTermination` to `NO`
which is labeled "Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out" in `Info.plist`.